# How to use ui:style defined CSS lables in my Widget Class?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

With UIBinder you can bind a css file in my Widget xml file as

```
<ui:style filed="style" src="myStyle.css" />

<g:HTMLPanel>
  <g:Button ui:field="mybtn" styleNamediv class="{style.container1}">hello</div>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

In my Widget Class I can do:

```
@UiField
Button mybtn
```

When I want to add a css class to the button in my Widget class then I would do something like:

```
mybtn.addStyleName(resources.someStyleLable());
```

Since I defined style in the xml file I cannot access any label of myStyle.css in my Widget class.

Is there some way I can access these labels in my Widget class?

Do I have to define a separate CssResource in my Widget class to access the css labels and to apply it to my button?

Answer (score 0):

In the  tag you need to add a type="com.a.a.MyCssInterface".  That interface can be defined as a inner class, and must extend CssResource.  You the add this line to your Widget.java file:
 @UiField MyCssInterface style

Comment: Could be more specific?

Comment: In the ui:style add the type=